# Can't fix syntax error in Inner Join query in C#

Tags: c#, join, syntax

I am trying to get the results of the query below and display it in a listBox but I keep getting this error:

> Syntax Error near 'a'.

Here is my code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=JOHZZ\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=parking;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=SA;Password=Roses2004");

SqlCommand c3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT targa" +
                               "FROM mjete AS m " + 
                               "INNER JOIN abonimi_mjet AS a" +
                               "ON m.mjeti_id = a.mjeti_id" +
                               "WHERE a.statusi = 'PASIV'" +
                               "AND m.klient_id = @idK", con);

con.Open();
c3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idK",idK);

SqlDataReader reader2 = c3.ExecuteReader();

while (reader2.Read())
{
    listBoxTarga.Items.Add(reader2.GetString(0));
}

reader2.Close();
con.Close();
```

I tried the same query in SQL Server Management Studio and it worked fine.

Thanks in advance for your help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a space between your lines. Using the + symbol adds them together as one string, just add a space at the end of each string.

```
SqlCommand c3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT targa " +
       "FROM mjete AS m INNER JOIN abonimi_mjet AS a " +
       "ON m.mjeti_id = a.mjeti_id " +
       "WHERE a.statusi = 'PASIV' " +
       "AND m.klient_id = @idK", con);
```

What you have now results in this string as the line breaks in your c# file are not string line breaks.

```
"SELECT targaFROM mjete AS m INNER JOIN abonimi_mjet AS aON m.mjeti_id = a.mjeti_idWHERE a.statusi = 'PASIV'AND m.klient_id = @idK"
```

---

### Side notes

You should wrap your `SqlConnection` instance in a `using` block to ensure it is always closed/disposed when you are done using it (even in the event of an Exception). The same goes for your `SqlDataReader` instance.

Comment: ... and you should also wrap the `SqlCommand` into a `using` block while you're at it ...